# Capistrano deploy bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am running Capistrano with a Wordpress website that I work on locally and deploy to a staging server or a production server on Digital Ocean. I've been working on it for months now. And today all of a sudden, the simple deployment script doesn't worK `scripts/deploy staging`

It's worked just fine & now it's not. Any ideas of what would cause it to break?

I get the error:

```
scripts/deploy: line 3: bundle: command not found
```

The command on line 3 is:

```
(bundle exec cap $1 deploy)
```

I'm using `ruby 2.0.0p645` 
And it looks like Capistrano `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.0'`

I actually have 3 websites that use this command and none of them are working all of a sudden. Did Cap do an update or could my system have an error somehow?

Comment: Also, I ran `gem list --local` and it shows that capistrano 3.2.1 is in fact installed along with cap-composer, bower, and npm are all installed...

Answer (score 0):

Simply try on the remote site:

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that. And every living thing I can find or think of. Even still after running `gem install bundler` it gives me the continued error.

Comment: Looks like it has to do with my update to El Capitan this weekend! But still can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be examined on the local site. Definitely bundler package is missing. Do you have the bundler gem listed after `gem list --local`?

Comment: Yes, both local and global. I have it under the site itself, as well as on my main system... 

    `bundler (1.10.6, 1.9.6)`
    `capistrano (3.2.1)`
    `capistrano-bower (1.1.0)`
    `capistrano-composer (0.0.6, 0.0.4)`
    `capistrano-npm (1.0.1)`

Comment: Is the bundler executable even available with `which bundle`? If not, you should check if the proper gem's `bin` directory exists in the PATH.